# Error at implementation of cloudinary in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cloudinary

I have a problem in the implementation of my expressjs code with cloudinary, when establishing the path of the image to upload, shows that path is not defined. I do not understand what is wrong.

This is my implementation:

The error is in the 14 line but i'm not undertand why:

```
app.post('/photos', upload.any(), function(solicitud, respuesta){
  //console.log(solicitud.body);
  if(solicitud.body.password == "emmanuel_1234567"){
    var data = {
      title: solicitud.body.title,
      description: solicitud.body.description,
      imageUrl: 'images/carousel/1.jpg'
    };
    var fotos = new Fotos(data);

    console.log(solicitud.files);

    cloudinary.uploader.upload(
      solicitud.files.photo_image.path, function(result) {

        fotos.save(function(error){
          console.log('Datos de fotografía guardados satisfactoriamente:');
          console.log(fotos);
          respuesta.render('index');
        });

    });
  }else{
    respuesta.render('photos/new');
    console.log('Contraseña incorrecta, por favor, intentelo nuevamente...');
  }

});
```

In the terminal show this:

```
arleys-mbp:emmanuel_upegui arley_cuadrado$ node app.js 
Conexión establecida correctamente!!! :)
[ { fieldname: 'photo_image',
    originalname: 'esta.png',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/png',
    destination: './uploads',
    filename: 'ef11a117af617cac01d78d18e6cd2924',
    path: 'uploads/ef11a117af617cac01d78d18e6cd2924',
    size: 63050 } ]
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
```

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Please post code and stacktrace inside your question on SO.

Comment: Please post code and data as text, not as (links to) paintings.

Comment: kalabalik, Bergi thanks for the recommendations, the truth is my first time writing here.
i edited the post!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the extension after the file name

For eg: Use this-  cloudinary.uploader.upload("/Users/Downloads/sample.jpg",function(result){console.log(result)});

instead of this-
  cloudinary.uploader.upload("/Users/Downloads/sample",function(result){console.log(result)});

Comment: I understand Aditi, but I believe this code short just working on absolutely routes and I wanna will be is work with dynamics routes.
or I'm wrong? Thanks!